# Bus timetables to Sidi Ifni, Morocco

Tags: buses, morocco, timetables

I'm travelling from Essaouira in southern Morocco to Laayoune (also written El Aaiun) in Western Sahara in October, and am considering breaking the journey roughly half way.  Reading some books and online reviews, Sidi Ifni seems an interesting choice of place, somewhat off the beaten track.

Lots of websites and books say that [CTM](https://ctm.ma/) and [Supratours](https://www.supratours.ma/) (the two main long-distance coach operators in Morocco) both serve Sidi Ifni, I assume on the route from Agadir to Laayoune.  However I'm struggling to find any details on their websites and neither coach operator is responding to my emails (whether in English or French).

Is anyone able to help me find the timetable, or recommend a booking agent who might be able to help?  Or if you know the coaches no longer serve Sidi Ifni, that would be useful to know too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CTM's website](https://ctm.ma/), as you link above, is happy to show me [schedules, prices, and a booking form](https://booking.ctm.ma/journeys?oStop=313&dCity=5629&oDate=2022-06-28&fareClasses=BONUS_SCHEME_GROUP.ADULT,1) for trips from Essaouria to Sidi Ifni (with a change in Agadir) for next week. They may simply not have loaded, or even decided, the schedules for the dates of your planned trip yet, if it is several months in the future.

According to [the PDF schedules on the ONCF website](https://www.oncf-voyages.ma/telecharger-horaires), Supratours Agadir/Laayoune service does not visit Sidi Ifni; instead, it goes via an inland route, passing through Bouizakarne and Guelmim. You could consider getting off the bus at Tiznit and taking a *grand taxi* there, but given the existence of the direct CTM service, this doesn't sound like the best way to go.

All of this is, of course, subject to change at short notice, and is best reconfirmed upon your arrival in Morocco if possible.